# How to write Apache-CXF post Rest Service Client with multiple Parameters

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I need to invoke a Rest POST API with multiple parameters. Following is the signature of post rest api

```
@POST
@Consumes({"application/json" })
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/service/postEmployeeBatch")
Response postEmployeeBatch(Employee employee, Organization org);
```

Following is the Rest Client code

```
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
provider.setMapper(mapper);
providers.add(provider);
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://test.com:8080/EmployeeService",            providers);
client.path("service/postEmployeeBatch/");
client.type("application/json").accept("application/json");
Employee emp = ...
Organization org = ....
//Response r = client.post(emp, org);
```

I am not clear how to invoke WebClient.post with multiple input parameters. I appreciate any help or direction on this,

Comment: Have you tried to pass objects in an array (Object [])?

Comment: yes but it is not working. What is the recommended way to invoke post method having multiple arguments.